# Changing search value via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

yesterday I created a topic here [Wordpress - How to change search value using a drop down selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36106515/wordpress-how-to-change-search-value-using-a-drop-down-selector)

and I figuret it with help of Fredrik but after a time I changed my idea and I removed select because it was not good inside input than i created some links using the font awesome icons wich now is looking better

My Final Search form is

```
<div class="searchbox">
<form action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" method="get"><button name="search" class="btn">
<span></span></button>
<input type="text" id="s" name="s" value="" />

<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="post" />

<div class="select_search">

<span class="wrs">
<i class="fa fa-video-camera" id="search_type_icon"></i>
<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</span>

<div class="drop_search">
<span data-searchtype="photos">
<i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
</span>
</div>

</div>

</form>
</div>
```

and My JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SearchPostValue(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var t = $(this);
var searchtype = t.attr('data-searchtype');
if (searchtype == 'post') {
$('#search_type_icon').removeClass('fa fa-picture-o').addClass('fa fa-video-camera');
$('[data-searchtype]').attr('data-searchtype', 'gallery').find('i').removeClass('fa fa-video-camera').addClass('fa fa-picture-o');
} else {
$('#search_type_icon').removeClass('fa fa-video-camera').addClass('fa fa-picture-o');
$('[data-searchtype]').attr('data-searchtype', 'post').find('i').removeClass('fa fa-picture-o').addClass('fa fa-video-camera');
}
$('.searchbox #search_type').attr('value', searchtype);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.searchbox .drop_search [data-searchtype]').click(SearchPostValue);
});
</script>
```

nothing worked :) its a shame for me but I spent hours and I cannot figure it out as I want

When I click on picture icon I want to change the value="post" to value="gallery" when I click on photo icon nothing happens.

My css

```
.select_search {
position:absolute;
right: 40px;
z-index:10;
display:inline-block;
width:58px;
height:31px;
cursor:pointer;
vertical-align:middle;
}

.select_search .wrs {
position:relative;
z-index:11;
display:block;
height:29px;
text-align:center;
}

.select_search:hover .wrs {
}


.fa-caret-down {
position:absolute;
top:6px;
right:7px;
width:7px;
height:4px;
-webkit-transition:0 .4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:0 .4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:0 .4s ease-in-out;
transition:transform .4s ease-in-out;
background-position:-300px 0;
}

.drop_search {
position:absolute;
z-index:10;
top:26px;
left:0;
display:none;
width:58px;
text-align:center;
}

.drop_search span {
display:block;
padding:0 0 4px;
}

.select_search:hover .drop_search {
display:block;
}
.select_search:hover .fa-caret-down {
-webkit-transform:rotateZ(-180deg);
-moz-transform:rotateZ(-180deg);
transform:rotateZ(-180deg);
position:absolute;
top:16px;
right:7px;
width:7px;
height:4px;
}

.fa-video-camera {
width:20px;
height:14px;
margin:6px 5px 0 0;
}

.fa-picture-o {
width:20px;
height:14px;
margin:6px 5px 0 0;
}
```

EDIt all html

```
<div class="searchbox">
<form action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" method="get"><button name="search" type="submit" class="btn">
<span></span></button>
<input type="text" id="s" name="s" value="" />

<input type="hidden" id="#search_type" name="post_type" value="post" />

<div class="select_search">

<span class="wrs">
<i class="fa fa-video-camera" id="search_type_icon"></i>
<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</span>

<div class="drop_search">
<span data-searchtype="photos">
<i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
</span>
</div>

</div>
</form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function SearchPostValue(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var t = $(this);
var searchtype = t.attr('data-searchtype');
if (searchtype == 'post') {
$('#search_type_icon').removeClass('fa fa-picture-o').addClass('fa fa-video-camera');
$('[data-searchtype]').attr('data-searchtype', 'gallery').find('i').removeClass('fa fa-video-camera').addClass('fa fa-picture-o');
} else {
$('#search_type_icon').removeClass('fa fa-video-camera').addClass('fa fa-picture-o');
$('[data-searchtype]').attr('data-searchtype', 'post').find('i').removeClass('fa fa-picture-o').addClass('fa fa-video-camera');
}
$('.searchbox #search_type').attr('value', searchtype);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.searchbox .drop_search [data-searchtype]').click(SearchPostValue);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Did you assign your `menuSearchClick` function to an event listener? I'm not seeing one in the code above.

Comment: Im sorry but Im not a js expert I just did a research on google and all my code is this do you know any other method?where should I add `menuSearchClick`

Comment: Which class/id/element do you want the interaction to occur on? What do you want `$(this)` to be?

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="post" />` value="post" so when I click on photo icon I want to change the value from post to gallery

Comment: There can't be a `type=hidden` event listener for a `click` event, since it's not visible to the end user. Sorry if I wasn't clear, but what do you want the user to click on in order for the function to execute?

Comment: So, I want to make a search form with multiple fields  if u check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36106515/wordpress-how-to-change-search-value-using-a-drop-down-selector you will understand what Im trying to make. `<i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>` is just a link wich opens on mouse hover when I gon on default link `<i class="fa fa-video-camera" id="search_type_icon"></i>` when I click on picture icon I want to replace it by removing the camera icon and in the same time I want to change value="post" to value="gallery" you are clear but my experiience is 0 with js :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no '#searchform #search_type' element in the html you provided, so that wont work.
Add that id (search_type) to your `<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="post" />` element.

and instead of changing it with .attr('value', newValue) you could just use

```
 $('#search_type').val(newValue);
```

As for whether the menuSearchClick(e) function is executed, you should check that with an alert() or console.log("check"). inside that function.
If these logs/alerts dont show up, you could add a onclick="menuSearchClick()" to your icon div.

Comment: thankyou for your help and replies I changed `<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="post" />` to `<input type="hidden" id="#search_type" name="post_type" value="post" />` by adding the id `#search_type` than as u said I forget the old earch form id and I change dit to ` $('.searchbox #search_type').val(searchtype);` but when I click on second icon `<i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>`  it doesnt change and remove the camera icon

Comment: I am sorry, I did not realize you are not aware of the 'selector' used by jQuery. You should read about them a little here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp
I believe this will help. id="#search_type" should be id="search_type"
the # sign lets jQuery know it has to search for elements with an id matching the string.
Did you add a onclick event to the icon element or check whether the mouseSearchClick function is executed?

Comment: hankyou you helped me so much and I got it working using
`$('.searchbox #search_type').attr('value', searchtype);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.searchbox .drop_search [data-searchtype]').click(menuSearchClick);
});` the only problem is value that doesnt change :) so now the icons are changing however thanks for all your spent time

Comment: Could you post the html of the element you want change the value of?

Comment: But you have no element with the id 'search_type', so jquery is not able to edit any value.

Comment: :( I have all the night here trying but I cant resolve anything :) if you have idea to complete this code with missed element would be very very appreciated

Comment: Do you have the code posted somewhere? Or would I be able to assist via teamviewer?

Comment: at the moment Im working localy I will try to upload it anywhere

Comment: but in localhost the icons are changing too but in the link these icons are not changing

Comment: That doesnt matter for now, however, I see that your id still has a # in it, that shouldnt be there in the html

Comment: wich id do you mean that one in input? #search_type?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106902/discussion-between-ikdekker-and-gazi).